# Twisted Python: Cannot write to a running spawned process

Tags: python, twisted, stdin, spawn

My question is, after spawning a process, the child process is looping to get data from its stdin. I would like to write new data to it using either Echo.Process.pipes[0].write(data) or Echo.Process.writeToChild(0,data), but both do not work. Would someone explain what's going on? Or how do I go around this problem?

This is the error I got:

```
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/encap/python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-9.0.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 146, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/usr/local/encap/python-2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-9.0.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 460, in doRead
    return self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
  File "pp1.py", line 30, in dataReceived
    Echo.Process.pipes[0].write(data)
exceptions.KeyError: 0
```

Thank You,

Q

```
from sys import executable
from os import environ
import os
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet import protocol
import sys

implementation = """\
import os
import time
import sys

print "in child", os.getpid()

while (True):
        a = raw_input("")
        if a: print a
"""


class Echo(Protocol):
    Process = None
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        if Echo.Process == None:
                pp = MyPP()
                Echo.Process = reactor.spawnProcess(pp, executable, [executable, "-c", implementation, data], env=environ, childFDs = {0:1, 1:1, 2:2})
        else:
                Echo.Process.pipes[0].write(data)
                #Echo.Process.writeToChild(0,data)
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade!"
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "out"
    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "error", data
    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited"
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded"
        print "quitting"

reactor.listenTCP(8200, EchoFactory())
print 'in parent', os.getpid()
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new process on each incoming connection and to redirect all input data to the process' stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.internet import protocol

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.pp = MyPP()
        reactor.spawnProcess(self.pp, 'cat', ['cat'])
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.pp.transport.write(data)
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.pp.transport.loseConnection()

class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade!"
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "out", data,
    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "error", data,
    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited"
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded"
        print "quitting"

factory = protocol.Factory()
factory.protocol = Echo
reactor.listenTCP(8200, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `childFDs` to `spawnProcess` and don't use the `pipes` attribute of the resulting process transport object.  Neither of these things does what you think.  If you drop the use of `childFDs` and switch back to `writeToChild`, you'll get the behavior you want.