# Embedding a Python shell in a webpage

Tags: python, embedding

I am working on a manuscript for introducing programming to beginners. Python is one of the two languages I cover in this book. I would like to setup up a webpage with an embedded Python shell for my readers to go and try things out. What would be the best way to go about it? I am aware of web apps like [repl.it](http://repl.it/). I would personally like to set something up myself, however.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [sample google appengine project](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/shell/README) that provides Python shell e.g., http://live.sympy.org uses it.

Or your JavaScript code (an Ajax shell) could communicate with a [sandboxed Pypy version](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) using something like [this Twisted WebSocket server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11729467/4279).

Comment: Thanks for the link to SymPy. Looks useful. I might be able to fork the project and get something up suitable for my needs. Also +1 to PyPy's sandbox link. There is a lot in that answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The fine folks at [repl.it](http://repl.it/) provide [a version of Python that is compiled in JavaScript](https://github.com/replit/empythoned) using LLVM and [EmScripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) - it's heftier than some of your other options (and possibly buggier) but it's completely client-side and therefore not vulnerable to some of the attacks that a server-side setup *might* be vulnerable to.

Comment: Thanks. I did check it out and will see if it is easier than getting something up using J.F. Sebastian's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new python shell provided by Datacamp.Its great and has a nice design.
[Check here!](https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp-light)

Answer (score 0):

Try [This](http://pyjs.org/).  It is a Python to javascript compiler.  Never used it, but I've heard about it before.  GLHF

Comment: To run the compiler you need Python. There is no Python in a browser