# Passing expressions and getting results from Python interpreter back to Django?

Tags: python, django, html

How do you pass and get results to a python interpreter where the input is coming from a website form?

For instance if you have a web form populated with basic arithmetic expressions like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

If you want to pass that expression like 1+1 or 4/6 to the python interpreter and get the result back to show on the web page is that possible? I'm using Django as framework.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant in the question, by interpreter do you mean the `interactive shell`  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a Python shell in a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813301/embedding-a-python-shell-in-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `eval()` to evaluate an expression.

```
>>> eval('4*4')
16
>>>
```

**DANGER**
Since eval() can execute arbitrary code you should never ever use it with user input. In your case I strongly discourage using it.

In short, there is no very easy way with built-in python functions.

You could try one of the solutions from the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106484/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-function-for-a-large-number-of-input-valu)

Answer (score 0):

Django *is* Python. You can write any valid Python code in your view.